# Python - sys.stdin.readline() - library

Tags: python, sys

```
import sys

lijst_salades = {'Eiersalade' : 5.99,
                 'Paprikasalade' : 6.05,
                 'truffelsalade': 3.99
                 }

input = (sys.stdin.readline())
print(lijst_salades[input])
```

it gives me an error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/some/random/dir/right/here/progr.py", line 9, in 
>       print(lijst_salades[input]) KeyError: 'truffelsalade\n'

Can someone explain what is did wrong?
If I use `print(lijst_salades['Eiersalade']` it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you read the `\n` char with the input passed, as the error state:

> KeyError: 'truffelsalade\n'

You should fix the code to:

```
import sys

lijst_salades = {'Eiersalade' : 5.99,
                 'Paprikasalade' : 6.05,
                 'truffelsalade': 3.99
                 }

input = (sys.stdin.readline()).rstrip()
print(lijst_salades[input])
```

Also, it is advised to add a testing to the input, because if the key doesn't exist it will also raise an error of type `KeyError`.

**Edit**

You can read about escape characters int the following links:

https://linuxconfig.org/list-of-python-escape-sequence-characters-with-examples

https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

Comment: i just started learning python. why does it read the \n? and what is it for? thank you for replying.

Comment: @Dakkie15 the `\n` is the newline character, when you press the Enter in the console/cmd/terminal it is added to the string automatically

Comment: @Dakkie15 see the link I added to the question about escape characters